# Data Retrieval errors: could not connect to server

Tags: database, postgresql, tcp, data-retrieval

could not connect to server: unable to connect to postgresql server.
connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) is the server running on host
and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

i tried to login into the xampp application to fetch the report and i got below errors

could not connect to server: unable to connect to postgresql server.
connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) is the server running on host
and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Please put errors in code blocks, and don’t mention the same one twice. Also, please clarify your question.

Comment: The error message is straight forward, either the server is not running or if it is it is not listening on port 5432. So you need to verify those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have started your server and that it is running, you can check the status of your Postgres,
If Postgres is not running, you can start it up depending on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the port 5432 is not already in use.